# CodeIgniter: “The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.” i need upload .dwg file

Tags: php, codeigniter

public function step8()
    {
        $data['application']=$this->license_m->get_byID($this->session->userdata('L_ID'))->row();

`if($this->input->post('submit')){
        $data= array(
            'DESC'   => $this->input->post('DESC',true),                            
            'L_ID'   => $this->session->userdata('L_ID')                            
        );

        if($_FILES['FILE_URL']['name'])
        {
                $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'dxf|dwg|gif|jpg|png|pdf|doc|docx|txt|rar|zip|bmp';
                $config['max_size'] = '0';
                $config['encrypt_name'] = true;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('FILE_URL'))
                    echo json_encode($this->upload->display_errors('<p>','</p>'));
                else
                {
                    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                    $FILE_URL=$upload_data['file_name'];
                    $data['FILE_URL']=$FILE_URL;
                    $status=$this->license_m->add_attachment($data);
                    }}}`

*/

Answer (score 1):

Go in *application/config/mimes.php* file and extend the allowed file types array with the `dwg`. Add the following line anywhere in the `$mimes` array  -

`'dwg' => 'application/acad'`

If you want to extend the list with more mime types, [this](http://www.hansenb.pdx.edu/DMKB/dict/tutorials/mime_typ.php) might be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

go in ci/application/config/mimes.php file and extend the allowed file types array with the dwg. add this line anywhere in the $mimes array-

'dwg' => 'application/acad'

basically if you want to add any kind of filetype you have to add it like this in ci/application/config/mimes.php

'extension' => 'application/mimetype'

and if there is a file type which have more than one mime type we have to define it in ci/application/config/mimes.php like

'extension' => array('application/mimetype','application/mimetype')

for example-:

'ogg'   =>  array('audio/ogg', 'video/ogg', 'application/ogg')

and remember if you are not declaring it at last then you have to put , after every declaration.....